# Did "Pirates of Silicon Valley" influence SO's name?

Tags: discussion, site-name

I was watching the 1999 classic *"Pirates of Silicon Valley"*, and, in a shot showing **Bill Gates** programming windows, this screen comes up.

Just wondering if this film had *anything* to with the naming of the site. Curious that's all :-)

I know it's a fairly common error in C/C++. Either way, it's a humourous reference.

[image: Stack Overflow]

*<sub>This originally comes from a [closed SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776892/did-pirates-of-silicon-valley-influence-sos-name).

It was suggested on SO I ask it here.</sub>*

Comment: I don't think stack overflow errors are that common, with many people shying away from recursion and all.

Comment: that's gotta be faked... everybody knows DOS only had upper-case letters :)

Comment: Why *didn't* they just migrate it if the comments all talk about it better being on Meta?

Comment: That overlay is in the wrong font, and it should be the same size as all of the rest of the screen, since the display is in text mode.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Jeff held a [Help Name Our Website](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001095.html) contest and Stack Overflow was the name that was most voted upon.

Answer (score 4):

I severely doubt it. Simply; it is common enough to be understood my devs, quite catchy, and wasn't taken. I don't speak for the actual team's decision, of course - this is just my understanding.